# Design patterns (Visitor vs Command vs Strategy)

Tags: design-patterns, command, strategy-pattern, visitor-pattern

I was considering the following case:
A person wants to choose a particular subject for researching. But once having chosen it, he has no control on the problem he receives within that subject.
In more general terms, a person wants a service, so he approaches a service provider. Once having chosen the service of his liking, he has no control over how the service is provided to him or over any of the service parameters (cost, etc.).

I narrowed down this case to three different design patterns: Command, Strategy and Visitor.

I am not sure how any of these corresponds to the situation at hand exactly. I just started learning design patterns, so could someone spot out the minor differences between the three patterns and contrast it with the situation?

Comment: You're talking about things at a very high level, but design patterns like those are much lower-level implementations. I don't see how they're connected either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about the Command pattern. Think of it as a person in a dinner. The person wants to order food. The person asks the waitress for a sandwich. Then the person has no control of how that steak is really made.